# Django static files not loading with no error signs

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

When I run the django server and try to load HTML files, it's not loading CSS files. I don't see any errors on the terminal or the website itself - just loading animation in the background. After I set up static files in settings.py, I ran collectstatic on the terminal which generated a new static file in the main file area with all the CSS/JS/fonts files.

```
~filepath

├── static/
│   ├── static/
│   │   └── admin/
│   │   └── css/    
│       └── fonts/
│       └── images/
│       └── js/
├── templates/
│   └── base.html/
│   └── _partials/
│      └── footer.html
│      └── navbar.html
│   └── pages/   
│      └── index.html
│      └── about.html
```

~settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tvfb/static')
]
```

```
~urls.py (project)
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

```
~urls.py (app)
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

```
~views.py
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/about.html')
```

```
~base.html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aos.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/ionicons.min.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/flaticon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/icomoon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    {% include '_partials/_navbar.html'%}
    <!-- Main Content -->
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- footer -->
    {% include '_partials/_footer.html'%}


    <!-- loader -->
    <div id="ftco-loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"><circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/><circle class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#F96D00"/></svg></div>


    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/aos.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/scrollax.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/google-map.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By saying server you mean on apache2 or ngix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase the **staticfilesdir**:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tvfb/static')
]
```

Will remain like:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

Run `python manage.py collectstatic` and dont forget to ***erase the cache of the browser as well***.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! May I ask for more clarification on erasing STATICFILES_DIRS as well as the caches of the browser? I would like to understand more in depth. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that it worked! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/ you can refer to this to learn more when to use staticfilesdir. Moreover, it is always advisable to clean the cache because the browser always tries to give the page from the cache and therefore sometimes it occurs that updates not shown.

Comment: @YeongHeo don't forget to accept the answers so others may find it easily as well.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! and Sorry, I just accepted your answer - my first time using Stackoverflow but thanks again!